# Android : checkbox in list view changing changing its state as we go from one activity to another and return back

Tags: android, checkbox

I am a beginner , creating a list view with checkboxes. When I check some checkboxes and return, then as I come back to same activity then checkbox get unchecked. Means they lose their state. So I tried to save their state in database. But I am getting exception as ClassCastException. SO how to achieve that ? Please help, my code is,

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // Event to display
            final Even eventzz = (Even) this.getItem(position);

            // The child views in each row.
            final CheckBox checkBox;
            TextView textView;

            // Create a new row view
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventsinfo, null);

                // Find the child views.
                textView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
                checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
                checkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't
                // have to call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.
                convertView.setTag(new EventViewHolder(textView, checkBox));

                 checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            int realPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                            if (isChecked) {
                                itemChecked.set(realPosition, true);
                                // update the database to store the new checked item:
                                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                                cv.put("list_position", realPosition);
                                statusDb.insert("status", null, cv);
                            } else {
                                itemChecked.set(realPosition, false);
                                // delete this position from the database because it was
                                // unchecked
                                statusDb.delete("status", "list_position = "
                                        + realPosition, null);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                 checkBox.setChecked(itemChecked.get(position));

                // If CheckBox is toggled, update the event it is tagged with.
                checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int realPosition = (Integer) checkBox.getTag();
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        Even eventz = (Even) cb.getTag();
                        eventz.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
else {
                // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call
                // findViewById().
                EventViewHolder viewHolder = (EventViewHolder) convertView
                        .getTag();
                checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
                textView = viewHolder.getTextView();
            }

             checkBox.setTag(new Integer(position));
    checkBox.setChecked(itemChecked.get(position));

            // Tag the CheckBox with the Event it is displaying, so that we can
            // access the event in onClick() when the CheckBox is toggled.
            checkBox.setTag(eventzz);

            // Display events data
            checkBox.setChecked(eventzz.isChecked());
            textView.setText(eventzz.getName());

            return convertView;
        }
```

Helper.java

```
 class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public Helper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // the list_position will hold the position from the list that are
        // currently checked
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE status (list_position INTEGER);";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Just for interface
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.eventstoremindlist);

        // Find the ListView resource.
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
    ArrayList<Even> eventList = new ArrayList<Even>();
    eventList.addAll(Arrays.asList(events));
    // Set our custom array adapter as the ListView's adapter.

    listAdapter = new EventArrayAdapter(this, eventList, null);

    // Retrieve the list of position that are checked(if any) from the
    // database
    statusDb = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor statusCursor = statusDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM status", null);
    int[] savedStatus = null;
    if ((statusCursor != null) & (statusCursor.moveToFirst())) {
        savedStatus = new int[statusCursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        do {
            savedStatus[i] = statusCursor.getInt(0);
            i++;
        } while (statusCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // if the cursor is null or empty we just pass the null savedStatus to
    // the adapter constructor and let it handle(setting all the CheckBoxes
    // to unchecked)


    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Exception is,

```
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.kalnirnay.kalnirnay.EventsToRemindActivity$Even
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.kalnirnay.kalnirnay.EventsToRemindActivity$EventArrayAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(EventsToRemindActivity.java:264)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:124)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-07 13:07:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of saving their state in database you can use :-

1. a static arraylist to store the position of checked checkbox, and read there checked value in getView() method before returning the view , 

2. u can use SharedPreferences to save state.

3. u can also look into ViewHolder concept !!

i think for such trivial use database is not suitable .

it will also save u some lines of codes !!

you can also refer this :-

[listview with check box](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)